# speed improvement in tesseract for many images

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

Do you have any ideas how to improve speed of tesseract for many images? I have 2 examples. First, I convert image to text that contains about 200 words. It takes **1 second**. Secondly, I have a loop of 100 images that contain 2 words and it takes **16 seconds**. 
How to improve time for the second case?

**Code 1:**

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
patch = './pdf_2_jpg/image.jpg'
multi = Image.open(patch)
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(multi)
```

**Code 2:**

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
patch = './pdf_2_jpg/image2.jpg'
single = Image.open(patch)
for x in range(100):
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(single,lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz6FT.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POALY.jpg)

Comment: You may better aks this kind of questions at  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are converting 100 images (or one image one hundred times) - do you expect improvements in the time it takes to convert any single image or improvements in the time it takes to iterate over 100 images?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I process tables, so I need to convert 300 images (cells) in less than 2 seconds. Unfortunately I do it in a loop and before I use the tesserect, I have to process each image using the openCV. Everything works very quickly in addition to the tesserect.I think the Tesseract starts every time and that's the reason...